# How to set default simulation device in Visual Studio?

Tags: ios-simulator, visual-studio-mac

Everytime I launch the simulator in VS it defaults to an iPod! How can I specify a particular iOS device as the default, so that I don't have to change it manually every session?

Comment: Same here, any clue?

Answer (score 0):

A way that worked for me, which include opening Xcode editor and setting the preferred device from there:

[image: How to set default simulation device in Visual Studio]

As we can see in the above picture, the default device simulator can be selected at the top of the window of xcode editor.

Comment: found an official answer: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/687857